# Angular show quizz results?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Trying to make quiz app but this code always return just one object...I have two radio groups and fetch value with `(ionSelect) ="radioGroupChange(questionId, answer)"` then put selected radios in `this.konacno` object array, but this code always put only one...

```
radioGroupChange(questionId, answer) {
    let answer: { id: number; answer: number } = { id: null, answer: null };
    this.konacno.forEach(element => {
      if (questionId !== element.id) {
        console.log(questionId);
        const index = this.konacno
          .map(function(item) {
            return item.id;
          })
          .indexOf(questionId);
        this.konacno.splice(index, 1);

        answer.id = questionId;
        answer.answer = answer;
        this.konacno.push(odgovor);

        console.log(this.konacno);
        console.log("Nije jednako");
      } else if (questionId === element.id) {
        console.log(questionId);
        const index = this.konacno
          .map(function(item) {
            return item.id;
          })
          .indexOf(questionId);
        this.konacno.splice(index, 1);

        answer.id = questionId;
        answer.answer = answer;
        this.konacno.push(odgovor);

        console.log(this.konacno);
        console.log("Jednako");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use same function to capture selection data from two different groups or do you need a selection group to select multiple items. Please explain

Comment: @HariPillai (ionSelect) ="radioGroupChange(questionId, answer)"

Comment: 1. What is `odgovor` in `this.konacno.push(odgovor);` I dont see the variable defined.

2. You can use `findIndex` instead of 

```
const index = this.konacno
          .map(function(item) {
            return item.id;
          })
          .indexOf(questionId);
```

3. Why are you splicing the array inside a foreach loop. That very array is being looped. Don't cut the branch you are sitting upon.